# Spotify API equivalent of Echonest top artists in genre

Tags: spotify, echonest

Using the now unavailable Echonest API, I can get a list of the top artists in a given genre like so:

http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/genre/artists?name=pop

I can search for artists in a given genre using the Spotify Web API like so:

http://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=artist&q=genre:pop

However there doesn't seem to be a way to order these results in any way. Is there a way to order search results, or perhaps cross-reference this information with another API call and get the desired result?